# Does Azure B2C provide "true" single sign-on between multiple applications

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I'm currently experimenting with Azure B2C and have created a tenant that is acting as a single identity server with 2 applications registered to it (on different domains).

The [Azure B2C documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-token-session-sso) suggests that is supports "Single sign-on (SSO) behavior across multiple apps".

The documentation gives the following as an example:
"once a user signs into an application, Contoso Shopping, he or she can also seamlessly sign into another one, Contoso Pharmacy, upon accessing it."

Whilst researching the meaning of single sign-on I came across [a question on StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13803/what-is-the-difference-between-federated-login-and-single-sign-on) where an answer describes 2 meanings of the term "single sign-on":

*(1) the user only has to provide credentials a single time per session, and then gains access to multiple services without having to sign in again during that session. But sometimes it's used to mean*

*(2) merely that the same credentials are used for multiple services; the user might have to login multiple times, but it's always the same credentials.*

Can anyone tell me  which of those 2 meanings is appropriate for Azure B2C? Does it or does it not provide/support "true single sign-on"?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 4):

It provides "true" single sign on (case 1) and of course case 2 as well (that is the basis for case 1).

In a B2C policy, you can control the SSO experience per Policy. 
In the "Token, session & SSO config" part you can configure the SSO behaviour:

[image]

As you can see, there is the possibility to limit the SSO to:

- Tenant (every application in B2C)
- Application (SSO through different policies on the same app)
- Per policy
- Disabled (No SSO)