# AzureB2C - SSO issue between UserFlow and CustomPolicy

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm facing an issue with AzureB2C and SSO.
I've got a custom policy and a UserFlow, both using SingleSignOn-Scope "tenant" and both use the same federated IdP (AzureAD).
Now, when using the one flow for signing in, SSO is working. But when signed in and switching to another app which is using the other flow, I get "We're having trouble signing you in..."
Regarding the custom policy, I did not change the SSO technical profiles from the starter pack, nor adding any other claims to the relying party. The output token of both flows look the same

Any idea what could be wrong or how I could debug this?

Comment: Have you set the sso config to "tenant" and set session life time? [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149581/does-azure-b2c-provide-true-single-sign-on-between-multiple-applications).Also check if you have browser cookies and javascript enabled.Try to login from the same browser window.

Comment: Yes, it's all set and actually working correctly if I stay within the same userFlow/policy. Let's say I login to App1 via CustomPolicy -> works. SSO in App2 via CustomPolicy -> works. SSO in App3 via UserFlow -> "we're having trouble signing you in"

Comment: Have you rechecked if the client id in app is correct : [MS reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-sign-into-app).

Comment: These are different apps. Of couse, they do have different ClientIDs. And yes, each app can sign in if you did not sign into another app before.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out what's going on here.
In fact, UserFlows use different signing keys then custom policies. UserFlows include some reference to Microsoft-internal keys which cannot be used in custom policies.
Therefore, I guess, the session cookie is encrypted differently and cannot be used accross UserFlows-CustomPolicies.
The same happens if you protect your Api with a UserFlow-Policy and you have your UI use a CustomPolicy. The API will throw an invalid signature exception.

Conclusion:
You either stay with customPolicies or UserFlows throughout your entire infrastructure.
(Somebody should actually address this to Microsoft)